# The performance of Panorama control in windows phone

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I'm using a panorama control to show some content, it contains four PanoramaItems. 
First I use "this.navigationservice.navigate()" navigating to another page, when I press the back button. It cost almost 1 second to get back to the panorama page.

Is there any dos and do-nots I should follow to improve the panorama performance?

Thanks.

P.S. I already known there are some suggestions in MSDN.

Comment: Do you have any code in the Loaded or NavigatedTo event handlers?

Comment: @Paul Diston , yes, but I use a bool object to make the loaded event just fire once like that:bool isLoaded; private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isLoaded)
                return;

            isLoaded= true;

            //code
        }

Comment: have you found the answer ?